# Script stores procedure creating in single line

Tags: excel, vba, oracle, stored-procedures

I have written VBA code in excel to create a SP in oracle and it working fine.
But when I opened SP in oracle it showing entire code in single line. I have tried known ways to give line breaks but nothing works.

My actual VB code:

```vb
If sp_exist_chk_flag > 0 Then
Else
   cmd_meta.CommandText = "create or replace PROCEDURE TEST_SP " & Chr(13) & _
    "As" & Chr(13) & _
    "REP DATA_REP.REP_ID%TYPE;" & Chr(13) & _
    "SELECT REP_ID INTO REP FROM DATA_REP WHERE REP_NAME='xyz';" & Chr(13) & _
    "COMMIT;" & Chr(13) & _
    "END;"

   cmd_meta.Execute
   MsgBox "SP Created"
End If
```

In Oracle I can see SP is created as below

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TEST_SP As REP DATA_REP.REP_ID%TYPE; SELECT REP_ID INTO REP FROM DATA_REP WHERE REP_NAME='xyz'; COMMIT; END;
```

My actual SP is too long, so my vb code making it very long line.
Please help me on this with VB code or oracle command to look like an actual SP with proper line breaks in oracle.

Comment: @ Peh - I clearly mentioned I am using excel and it is a VBA code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it will make a difference, but try using the `vbCrLf` constant instead of `Chr(13)`.

```
If sp_exist_chk_flag > 0 Then
Else
   cmd_meta.CommandText = "create or replace PROCEDURE TEST_SP " & vbCrLf & _
    "As" & vbCrLf  & _
    "REP DATA_REP.REP_ID%TYPE;" & vbCrLf  & _
    "SELECT REP_ID INTO REP FROM DATA_REP WHERE REP_NAME='xyz';" & vbCrLf  & _
    "COMMIT;" & vbCrLf  & _
    "END;"

   cmd_meta.Execute
   MsgBox "SP Created"
End If
```

Comment: If Linux\Unix is used try `Chr(10)` which is a `vbLf` instead of `Chr(13)`.

Comment: And it not that `Chr(10)`

Comment: @dcp - Thanks it working :)

Comment: @Scales - That's great!  Please be sure to accept the answer if it solved your issue.